# How to save a data in to array without DB

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uibutton

How to save the newly added value to the NSMuttable array,and i want reset the newly added item array by button click?Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add it by doing the following

```
array = [nsmutablearray arraywithcontentsoffile:path];
nsstring *item= @"string";
        [array addObject:item];
        [array writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

to remove it in a different method put either :

```
        [array removeObjectAtIndex:1];
```

or

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager]removeItemAtPath:Path error:nil];
```